# Java - Array of Inner Classes inside of Outer Class

Tags: java, polymorphism, inner-classes, outer-classes

Let's say I have:

```
public class A {
  public A() {
    ...
  }
  ...

  public class B {
    public B() {
      ...
    }
    public void doSomething() {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }

  public class C {
    public C() {
      ...
    }
    public void doSomething() {
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

If I wanted to make an ArrayList that could contain both B and C in such a way that I could call `myArray.get(i).doSomething()` inside of A, what type would I want to declare my ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner classes have to implement an interface; otherwise the compiler can't be sure that all classes have doSomething() methods and won't allow it.

Answer (score 5):

`List<myInterface>`. You'll also need an interface for `B` and `C`:

```
interface myinterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

And both `B` and `C` must `implement myInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want that define an ArrayList as:

```
ArrayList<T> al = new ArrayList<T>();
...
al.get(0).doSomething();
```

No, you could not yet. You also need to declare a parent class named T or interface T which has a method doSomething and your class A.B and A.C need to implement T.